# Life-time of object declared in the second "parameter" of 'for' statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, destructor

I have just discovered that it is possible to place a declaration also in the second "parameter" of a for-statement. But I was not able to find anywhere how it behaves with regard to the construction/destruction of the object declared in that parameter.

Let's have this simple code:

```
struct C {
  C() { puts("constr"); }
  ~C() { puts("destr"); }
};

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; auto h = std::make_unique<C>(); i++) {
    puts("in");
  }
}
```

Please could you tell me when `h` is destroyed? (after `puts("in")`, `i++`, ...?). How does it behave with `break;` and `continue;`?

Thanks for clarification!

Comment: IMO, It will be created and destroyed on every step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lifetime of the object created within the loop condition is bound to the scope of the loop body, and can also be used within the iteration expression (`i++` in your example). The condition is evaluated at the beginning of *each iteration*, the object it creates lasts until the end of that iteration, is then destroyed and created again for the next iteration, and so on. `break` or `continue` statements do not influence the lifetime of the object created in the condition.

The reasoning is as follows. From [[stmt.for]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter#stmt.for), we can see that a for loop is defined in terms of a while loop.

> The for statement
>
> ```
> for ( init-statement condition ; expression ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     init-statement
>     while ( condition ) {
>         statement
>         expression ;
>     }
> }
> ```

Jumping back to [[stmt.while]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter#stmt.while) then yields the answer to your question (emphasis mine):

> When the condition of a while statement is a declaration, the scope of the variable that is declared extends from its point of declaration ([basic.scope.pdecl]) to the end of the while statement. A while statement whose condition is an initialized declaration of some variable t is equivalent to
>
> ```
> label:
> { // start of condition scope
>     condition; // declares t
>     if (t) {
>         statement
>         goto label;
>     }
> } // end of condition scope
> ```
>
> [ Note: **The variable created in the condition is destroyed and created with each iteration of the loop**. [...]]

Comment: Thanks! With this explanation I can derive also behavior of `break` (destroy locals, destroy condition, destroy init) and `continue` (destroy locals, destroy condition) and a possibility to use "condition object" also in the 3-rd `for` "parameter"...

Comment: Right, I should also add this to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Think it simple, if I'm the language designer, the following statements:

```
for ( a; b; c ) d
```

and

```
for ( a; { b }; { c }) { d }
```

Should be strictly equivalent

It is obvious that some variables defined in `a` can be used in `b`,`c`,`d`, So only `a` is special.

#### BTW

I think the for-statement in Scala is more beautiful. In Scala `for` is just a syntax suger:

```
for (i <- v) s  <==> v.foreach(i => s)
```

Where

```
i => s
```

is the lamba syntax like:

```
[](auto i){ s }
```

in C++11

It is universal true, variable `v` of every type which defines function `foreach` can be used in `for` statement.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The closest it gets mistakes `b` for `a`